# What is a polynomial with infinite number of terms?

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, terminology

My instructor commented that a structure function $\phi(G)$ of a graph is a polynomial if a finite number of terms. So what is the thing with infinite number of terms? Why not polynomial?

Comment: A "[formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series)."

Comment: Sometimes that is called a formal power series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Definition_of_the_formal_power_series_ring

Comment: Is $e^x:=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$ a polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with an infinite number of terms is called a power series. We ought to be careful here though. There are distinctions to be made.

You can $\textit{formally}$ write down a power series and view it as a purely algebraic object. We call these "formal power series".

You can also think of a power series as a function. In which case it may or may not make sense to plug in certain values. For instance:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n $$

You can plug in any number for $x$ that is in the interval $(-1,1)$, but any number outside that interval will cause that sum to be infinite or not exist.